# Node.js cannot recognize characters from the serial port

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming, c, node.js

The following script prints everything fine, it recognizes integers from the serial port, but cannot recognize characters.  The if statement does not work with characters.  I have tried both == and === in the if statement

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport')
var Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline
var serialPort = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyAMA0', {//ttyAMA0
  baudRate: 9600
})

var parser = new Readline()
serialPort.pipe(parser)
parser.on('data', function (data) {
if(data === 'c'){/// c is not recognized
  console.log('data received: ' + data)
}

})
serialPort.on('open', function () {
  console.log('Communication is on!')
})
```

The Arduino code is as follows:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(12, 13); // RX, TX
int x = 0;
int y = -30000;
int z = 0;
String data;
char command = 'q';
int left = 0;
int right = 0;
int left_pwm = 0;
int right_pwm = 0;

void setup() {
  mySerial.begin(9600);     // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
  Serial.begin(9600);
  }
void loop() {//map and compass data
if (y==30000) {
 mySerial.println('c');
 delay(5);
 mySerial.println(299);
 delay(5);
 z = -25000;
 } 

 if(z==30000){
 mySerial.println('lon');   
 delay(5);    
  mySerial.println(529);
  delay(5);
  mySerial.println('lat');   
 delay(5);
   mySerial.println(522);
          y = -30000;
    }
  y++; z++;

  if (!mySerial.available()) {
    return;
  }

  data = mySerial.readString();
   sscanf(data.c_str(), "%c%01d%01d%03d,%03d", &command, &left, &right, &left_pwm, &right_pwm);

  if (command == 'n') { // we got a navigation command
    // update the GPIO accordingly, this only happens once after a new 'n' command has been received
    Serial.print(command);
    Serial.print(left);
    Serial.print(right);
    Serial.print(left_pwm);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.println(right_pwm);
    }

    }////end loop
```

Comment: why is this command not before the `if` statement? `console.log('data received: ' + data)`

Comment: Have you tried trimming `data` from all white space?

Comment: @jsotola  Console Log is telling me the if statement is not working.

Comment: @chrisl   data = data.trim();  Bingo,   Thanks!

Comment: @HarryHobson, console log inside the `if` statement is preventing you from seeing what data is being received ... it is a poor debugging procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the line parser in Nodejs, it does not remove all line ending characters. I think (though I currently cannot cite it), that only the `'ņ'` character is removed from the string. But `Serial.println()` sends `"\r\n"` as line ending. That means, that your string is "c\r", which is not equal to "c".

By using the `trim()` method of the String type, you can remove all white space from start and end of the string, including line ending characters like `'\r'`.